# Prestashop 1.7 Smarty engine passing variable from controller to .tpl file

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Why in the template file variable's properties are get by dot (.) but added variables are get by arrow (->). In mainmenu.tpl I have:

```
public function renderWidget($hookName, array $configuration)
{

    $this->smarty->assign([
        'menu' => $this->getWidgetVariables($hookName, $configuration),
    ]);
    
    // assign new variable
    $id = 661;
    $id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
    $product = new Product((int) $id, false, (int) $id_lang);
    $this->smarty->assign('product', $product);

    return $this->fetch('module:ps_mainmenu/ps_mainmenu.tpl');
}
```

and in ps_mainmenu.tpl:

```
    {$menu.label}
    {$product->name}
    {$product.name} //not render
```

How to acccess every property by dot?

Answer (score 0):

The (.) accessor is used when referencing properties of associative array, and in this type are passed most of prestashop objects. So object should be casted to array:

```
$this->smarty->assign('product', (array)$product);
```

Answer (score 0):

My shot,
you shoul also

```php
$this->smarty->assign('product', $product);
```

change to

```php
$this->smarty->assign('product' => $product);
```

btw `$product` isn't it global so it's easy to access from anywhere?